# Calling Activity from notification forces new task resulting in a "blank" activity

Tags: android, notifications

I have an app which might receive a push notification. This push notification should start an activity when the user clicks on it. So pretty standard. I got it working on the emulator and on my Galaxy S4, but the Nexus device is giving me a head ache.

At first I got:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: start Intent
```

on that particular Activity, I "fixed" this by inserting android:exported="true" into that Activity in the manifest xml. Not sure if this was the right approach, but I couldn't find a better one.

Now I am getting

```
​startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent
```

Activity gets started, but these Extra Variables seem to be "null":

```
opponentUsername = getIntent().getExtras().getString("opponentUsername");
gameId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("gameId");
```

Resulting in an "empty" activity.

this is how I launch the activity in my BroadcastReceiverClass:

```
Notification n = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, SS9ChatActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("opponentUsername", dataObject.getString("oppo"));
intent.putExtra("gameId", dataObject.getString("game"));
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, intent, 0);
n.setLatestEventInfo(ctx, "Game", tickerText, pi);

n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;                 
n.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
nm.notify(1, n);
```

What I tried so far is, inserting `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in my activity, but this didn't seem to fix it

So what am I doing wrong here? Why are Nexus devices so different from the emulator and my Galaxy S4? There my app works fine.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Here is my manifest in full

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.testapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />      

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

        <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
            android:name="com.testapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.testapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />       

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/noAnimTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>        
        <activity
            android:name="com.testapp.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

<activity android:name="MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name" 
          android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"/>          

<activity android:name="SS9ChatActivity"
          android:launchMode="singleTop"
          android:exported="true"
          android:label="@string/app_name" 
          android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"/>

<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" 
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>     

<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

    <category android:name="com.testapp" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>        
<receiver 
    android:name="com.testapp.PushBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="false"
    >
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.testapp.Push" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>         

 <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you sure that these variables are not empty ?

dataObject.getString("oppo) & dataObject.getString("game")

Comment: yes 100% because I can see the call in the Log and I can see that the variables are filled plus as I said, it works like that in the emulator and the error "startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent" suggests that something non standard is happening here

Comment: Yep. Got it. Can you post your manifest file ?

Comment: just included my manifest :-) thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`singleTop` is the correct answer. However, you need to implement [onNewIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) as the incoming `Intent` is not automatically set so that you can retrieve its values via `getIntent()`:

```
protected void onNewIntent (Intent intent) {
  setIntent(intent); // now the rest of your code can use getIntent() as before
  handleIntent(); // this should also be called from onCreate as well
}
```

Comment: thank you, i will try this as soon as possible. is there a reason why my code works on the emulator and on the s4 but i need to go an extra mile for a nexus device?